# QlistWidget how to select items one by one

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt4, pyqt5, qlistwidget

i want open images sequence and i load all images in a list; i want when i click to a button called next the current list index change from 1 to 2 than from 2 to 3 ...etc right the last frame.
this code always give me the last frame

```
 self.nextbtn.clicked.connect(self.changeitem)
 def changeitem(self):
        self.listWidget.count()
        count_list = self.listWidget.count()
        self.listWidget.setCurrentRow(0)
        for i in range(count_list):
            self.listWidget.setCurrentRow(i+1)
```

Comment: i find simple solution : ( update)

Comment: Please do not post the solution inside your question, instead please put it as a new answer.

Comment: because in the comment i can't write the code ; it look like a text

Answer (score 0):

solution :

```
def changeitem(self):
    cur = self.listWidget.currentRow()
    self.listWidget.setCurrentRow(cur+1)
```